# Setting a header 400 with custom description -- is this possible?

Tags: php

Can I set a custom text in a header HTTP/1.0, like this:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 400 Custom text for debugging);
```

instead of:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
```

Could you tell me if it is valid?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: While it works, I would like to ask if it may cause any problems.

Comment: Cause problems where? In a production environment?

Comment: Yes, in a production environment and on the client side.

Comment: What do you mean problems?  We need more information.

Comment: I develop a plugin for image management. Images are served with a PHP file that is requested with AJAX. First, the PHP script checks if an image file exists. If negative, a header 400 is set. If positive, the PHP script outputs an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. But...

The reason why error codes and error messages exist is that so we can apply some standards in order to simplify the communication. That's the idea of a protocol - standards and rules in a conversation.

Now if we think, why there are both error codes and error messages, it might be that the messages are just a description of the code, meaning that if you changed it (without changing the error code) it would probably do no harm.

Still, this only depends on those who are communicating not depending on the http message, but instead on the code.

Having said these, I would go for an extra header instead of modifying an existing one. Just set a new header field for debugging.